# Datasnap remove expired sessions Delphi

Tags: delphi, service, firemonkey, datasnap

an app created for the mechanics of a company is controlled through the `datasnap` windows service active on the server. Now, these mechanics are often on the road and disconnect from the server. When the technician opens the app again and connects to the service, a new session is created and the old session is not deleted. This results that there is an accumulation of expired sessions that are not removed. how can I make sure the expired sessions are removed?

If I forgot some information please let me know and I add it to the question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg In my case, the client side doesn't get an exception it just makes a new session. besides, I don't work with the `TDSRestConnection` but with the `TFDConnection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some documentation form embarcadero I've added the following to my `DSTCPServerTransport.OnConnect` event:

```
 Event.Channel.EnableKeepAlive(30000);
```

where 30000 the amount of milliseconds is.

on my client-side i added the following to my `FDConnection.Onrecover` event:

```
AAction := TFDPhysConnectionRecoverAction.faRetry;
```

This solves my problem with the unused sessions.